# Is "animation" an abstract noun?

Tags: grammar, articles, abstract-nouns

There are some web page elements. Let's call them "sprites". There are also two kinds of animations (two pieces of code). For each mentioned above web page element, I use one kind of animations. Can I use the phrase: *"set **an** animation for each sprite"*? Is the animation an abstract noun?

Comment: It depends on the context. Are you talking about the *process* or the end product?

Comment: You should always include at least a complete example sentence, along with as much context as necessary. Start it with ">" so the example is set out from the rest of your question.

Comment: *concrete/abstract* and *count/mass* are independent properties of nouns.

Comment: @JasonBassford, I mean end product.

Comment: @amI, when you know what the kind of nouns (concrete or abstract) a word belong to, you know what rule of choosing an article applies to.

Comment: No -- 'Water' can be mass or count, but always concrete.  'Truth' can be mass or count, but always abstract.

Comment: @aml, of course, we should consider other aspects of a word, and also a context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

> Then you need to set **an animation type** for each sprite.

*type* referring to code. Even if you leave out "type", it is still implied and makes "animation" a regular noun.